# Using thymeleaf to post form data to a Controller that uses @ModelAttribute (complex objects)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

There is the `Element` class:

```
public class Element {

    private Long id;
    private Name name;

    // Getters and Setters ...
}
```

And the `Name` class:

```
public class Name {

    private String en;
    private String fr;
    private String de;

    // Getters and Setters ...
}
```

There is a getElementsController:

```
@GetMapping("/elements/create")
public String getElementsCreate() {
    return "private/new-element";
}
```

There is a `NewElementController` controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/elements/create")
    public String postElementsCreate(@ModelAttribute Element element) {

        System.out.println(element)
        return null;
}
```

There is a form that posts data to the NewElementController:

```
<form method="post" th:object="${element}" th:action="@{/elements/create}">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="id" placeholder="Id"/>
    // How should I make the input fields for: 
       element.name.en ?
       element.name.fr ?
       element.name.de ?
    <button type="submit">Save element</button>
</form>
```

Setting the Id works, but I can not access the `name` field (it is an object)
I have tried with `th:field="*{name}"` and with `th:field="*{name.en}"`, but it does not work in that way.

Comment: Do you have model.addAttribute("element", new Element()) in @GetMapping method ?

Comment: I have now updated the question with @GetMapping controller. Do I have to put there something?

Comment: as @GurkanYesilyurt said you need to set the new element object to your map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
<form method="post" th:object="${element}" th:action="@{/elements/create}">
    <input type="text" name="id" th:value="*{id}" placeholder="Id"/>
    <input type="text" name="name.en" th:value="*{name.en}" placeholder="Name (EN)"/>
    <input type="text" name="name.fr" th:value="*{name.fr}" placeholder="Name (FR)"/>
    <input type="text" name="name.de" th:value="*{name.de}" placeholder="Name (DE)"/>
    <button type="submit">Save element</button>
</form>
```

Yor controller method for GET should be like this:

```
@GetMapping("/elements/create")
public String getElementsCreate(Model model) {
    Element element = new Element();
    Name name = new Name();
    element.setName(name);
    model.addAttribute("element", element);
    return "private/new-element.html";
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but it gives me the following error: `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "element.name.en" (private/new-element:37)] with root cause org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null`

Comment: Like gurkan said, Do you have model.addAttribute("element", new Element()) in @GetMapping method ?

Comment: Please check the update on my question with @GetMapping. Do I have to add something there?

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. It solved the problem with the small modification on the input field which works with this:                                 <input type="text" name="element.en" th:value="${element.name}" placeholder="Name (EN)"/> Please update your answer with this small modification so I can accept your answer.

Comment: If you change binding like that you modified, you will not get the bind value if you want to use the form for element edit in future. Please see the updated controller method and form. Thanks