# Pass data from Thymeleaf template to springboot controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have simple web application written using Springboot and Thymeleaf templates. Report controller receives the data from form and builds the TestPlanReportResponse object which is added as model attribute like this:

```
@PostMapping("/report")
public String homeSubmit(@ModelAttribute HomeFormInput homeFormInput, Model model, Errors errors) {
    final TestPlanReportResponse response = new TestPlanReportResponse(homeFormInput);
    model.addAttribute("allData", response);
    return "charts";
}
```

I can work with that data in "charts" thymeleaf template and show the data I need, but I need to send exactly the same object back to controller when button is clicked, but i getting TestPlanReportResponse
object as parameter with nulls set.

```
@PostMapping("/report/send")
public String sendReport(@ModelAttribute TestPlanReportResponse reportData, Model model) {
    //reportData contains just nulls
}
```

Here is how my button is set in charts template:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/report/send}" th:object="${allData}" method="post">
        <button type="submit">Send the report</button>
</form>
```

So my question is how to send the object back from thymeleaf template? Should i create a hidden input and put there the "allData" object just to send it back? It looks for me like dirty hack. What would be the appropriate way to pass data back? I want to have this app stateless so don't to store the data on a server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used to work with Spring and Thymeleaf and form, we had the same issue, passing the data back and forth between a form, the template, and different controllers.
And what you suggest is what we did, we used hidden input as dirty as it may look,it was the standard suggested answer, we did not find anything better.

You need to create an input, with a type a value and link it to a field, like this:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/report/send}" th:object="${allData}" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" th:value="*{allDataValue1}" th:field="*{allDataField1}" />
//Do this for all your attributes/values that you wish to pass to the controller
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Send the report</button>
    </form>
```

Though, i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192373/using-thymeleaf-to-post-form-data-to-a-controller-that-uses-modelattribute-com), you can try looking into this thread

Comment: Thank you @Youri it looks like this is the way to solve it

Comment: Glad to hear it